# Configure and use 2 Firebase projects simultaneously in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to use 2 different firebase projects simultaneously in my flutter app.

I'm using the below command to add project configs into my flutter app:

```bash
flutterfire configure --project="proj1" --platforms="android,ios" --out="lib/firebase_options.dart" -y;
flutterfire configure --project="proj2" --platforms="android,ios" --out="lib/proj2.firebase_options.dart";
```

and want to configure them at the same time with the below code in the main function:

```dart
import 'firebase_options.dart' as proj1;
import 'proj2.firebase_options.dart' as proj2;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Future.wait([
    Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: proj1.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    ),
    Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "Project2",
      options: proj2.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    ),
  ]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

---

But when I'm trying to run the configure commands it is asking if I want to override the `firebase_app_id_file.dart` as it is already configured for project1.

When I type `no` (cuz proj1 is main one), I get the following error:

```bash
Unhandled exception:
FirebaseAppIDAlreadyExistsException: Firebase app ID file {{project_path}}/ios/firebase_app_id_file.json is already up to date.
#0      FirebaseAppIDFile.write (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_app_id_file.dart:71:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1):

maintainer of FlutterFire here. If you're trying to configure multiple environments, I'd recommend using the latest FlutterFire CLI dev release. You need to run:

```bash
 dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli 0.3.0-dev.16 --overwrite
```

To get the latest dev release. The "firebase_app_id_file.json" file will no longer appear as a file in your codebase, it is handled in the background (hidden away in the ".dart_tool" directory) which allows us to track multiple "firebase_app_id_file.json" files for every one of your apps.

If you would like to get started, here is a PR description with some helpful ideas on what commands to run: https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/pull/142#issue-1527687743

I'm actually looking to do another dev release very soon which will improve the `flutterfire configure` command a bit further. For example, it will auto-detect if you have Crashlytics as a dependency and insert the upload symbols script automatically into your Xcode project which runs at build time without you having to input anything.

Track this issue for further updates:https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/14

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Russell, I got your answer but I'm looking for something different.

I want to use 2 firebase projects _simultaneously_ in a single flutter app (no flavours, only main release build). Like for e.g.

Suppose my flutter app have 2 forms, I want to add data from `form 1` in firebase `project1` and and data from `form 2` in firebase `project2`. 

And both these forms are available in a single release build or flavour. How can I do that? As there is only 1 `google-services.json` & `GoogleService-Info.plist` file that contains configuration for only one project.

Comment: @Russell How is this coming a long? I need to setup crashlytics for different flavors / firebase projects but don't know how